# Regex stemmer code explanation

Tags: python, regex

Can someone please explain what does this code do?

```
def stemmer(word):
    [(stem,end)] = re.findall('^(.*ss|.*?)(s)?$',word)
    return stem
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It splits a word into two parts: `stem` and `end`. There are three cases:

1. The word ends with `ss` (or even more `s`): `stem <- word` and `end <- ""`
2. The word ends with a single `s`: `stem <- word without "s"` and `end <- "s"`
3. The word does not end with `s`: `stem <- word` and `end <- ""`

This is done by a regular expression which captures the full word (due to `^....$`). The first part (i.e. `stem`) consists either of as much as possible ending in `ss` (`.*ss`) or if that is not possible of as less as possible (`.*?`). Then possibly an ending `s` is taken to be the `end` part.

Note that in the first case (as much as possible ending in `ss`) there can never be an additional `s` for the `end` part.