# Regex and stemming

Tags: regex

I have a stemmer that outputs some words from a file. I want a Regex that will find every word that ends with "e" and then remove the "e".

```
>>> def stemmer(word):
[(stem,end)] = re.findall('^(.*e)?$',word)
return stem
```

Could you please help me to get it right?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you in the [same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629433/regex-stemmer-code-explanation) as Ray Hmar? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `\b([A-Za-z]+)e\b` to your input globally, not only to a word.

`\b` is the word anchor.